# jquery tab not selected after page reloaded using window.location.reload(url)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-tabs

When I click a refresh button on my page the page that reloads doesn't seem to be selectiung the first tab as it usually does with a refresh or reload page?

My jquery tabs are set up as you'd normally find anywhere.

Any ideas?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

**tabs**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li><a href="#priority">Priority</a></li>
        <li><a href="#urgent">Urgent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#potential">Potential</a></li>
        <li style="margin-left:75px">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="priority">
    </div>
    <div id="urgent">
    </div>
    <div id="potential">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Button call**

```
 <input type="button" id="btnRefresh" value="Refresh" onclick="do_refresh()"/>
```

**do_refresh function**

```
function do_refresh()
{
var man_num = document.getElementById('txtOpCode').value;
var ps=document.getElementById('drpSect').value;
var url = "auto.php?v=l&man_num="+man_num+"&ps="+ps;
window.location.reload(url);        
}
```

**jQuery tabs function**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
  var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
  tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
  $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
     return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: In fact it's all the jQuery that isn't reloading....

Comment: Some code would be nice. I don't want to break into your house to debug code, again...

Comment: Code added. Does seem to reload the JQuery after refresh ....

Comment: +1 for Blender's awesome comment :)

Comment: haha ...like I said pretty much standard jQuery tabs code.

Comment: When you inspect the DOM, can you see if the first tab content is hidden?

Comment: Ok I changed the way this works and I was trying to display as tab section on reload I think before it had been dynamically created. I've now removed that and jquery appears to be loading ok now. So the user will have to select an option from the dropdown but for now that is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed the way this works and I was trying to display as tab section on reload I think before it had been dynamically created. I've now removed that and jquery appears to be loading ok now. So the user will have to select an option from the dropdown but for now that is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple tabs</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)test2\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

        switch(myCookie){
            case "undefined":
                tab_1();
                break;
            case "tab1":
                tab_1();
                break;
            case "tab2":
                tab_2();
                break;
            case "tab3":
                tab_3();
                break;
        }
    });

    function tab_1(id){
        $('.tab-1cont').show();
        $('.tab-2cont').hide();
        $('.tab-3cont').hide();
        document.cookie = "test2="+id;
    }

    function tab_2(id){
        $('.tab-1cont').hide();
        $('.tab-2cont').show();
        $('.tab-3cont').hide();
        document.cookie = "test2="+id;
    }

    function tab_3(id){
        $('.tab-1cont').hide();
        $('.tab-2cont').hide();
        $('.tab-3cont').show();
        document.cookie = "test2="+id;
    }
</script>

<ul>
    <li onclick="tab_1(id)" id="tab1" class="tab_001">Tab-1</li>
    <li onclick="tab_2(id)" id="tab2" class="tab_002">Tab-2</li>
    <li onclick="tab_3(id)" id="tab3" class="tab_003">Tab-3</li>
</ul>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="tab-1cont"><h1>Tab 1 container</h1></div>
<div class="tab-2cont"><h1>Tab 2 container</h1></div>
<div class="tab-3cont"><h1>Tab 3 container</h1></div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a bit ?